# Notice: Undefined variable: username, password, dataAction

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I have tried several different methods and have looked at several similar questions in hopes of getting my page to process correctly.  However, I have been unsuccessful.  I am getting three notices that says Undefined variable:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username
Notice: Undefined index: password
Notice: Undefined index: dataAction
```

```php
$usernameLabel = "Username:";
$usernameName = "username";
$usernameValue = $_POST[$usernameName];

$passwordLabel = "Password:";
$passwordName = "password";
$passwordValue = $_POST[$passwordName];

$submitName = "dataAction";
$submitValue = "Submit";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the value is set

```
$usernameLabel = "Username:";
$usernameName = "username";

 //check if the $_POST array is populated and contain this key and there is a value associated to it
if(isset($_POST[$usernameName]))
{
   $usernameValue = $_POST[$usernameName];
}
```

Comment: why couldn't you just do `$usernameValue = $_POST["username"];`?